# Corrupted message in custom exception

Tags: c++, string, c++11, exception

I'm trying to implement a custom class exception.

The exception itself works, but I recieve a corrupted output

```
#include <stdexcept>

namespace Exception{

class LibraryException : public std::runtime_error
{
public:
   explicit LibraryException(const std::string& message)
      : std::runtime_error(""),
        prefix_("LibraryException: "),
        message_(message)
   {
   }

   const char* what() const noexcept override
   {
      std::string out;
      out += prefix_;
      out += message_;
      return out.c_str();
   }

private:
   std::string prefix_;
   std::string message_;
};

class BadSizeException : public LibraryException
{

public:
   explicit BadSizeException() : LibraryException("Library: Bad Size\n")
   {
   }
};
}
```

Output when I try to raise the exception:

> °áó°áóxception: Bad Size

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Once the `what` function returns (with the pointer) what happens to the local variable `out` (and the data the returned pointer is pointing to)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Drew said you used local object pointer outside its scope. Possible solution.

```
class LibraryException : public std::runtime_error
{
public:
   explicit LibraryException(const std::string& message)
      : std::runtime_error(""),
        prefix_("LibraryException: "),
        message_(message)
   {
   }

   const char* what() const noexcept override
   {
      buffer_ = prefix_ + message_;
      return buffer_.c_str();
   }

private:
   std::string prefix_;
   std::string message_;
   mutable std::string buffer_;  // Now buffer will live between what() calls.
};
```

`mutable` is because of constness of `what()`. This way you can alterate the value of `buffer_`.

Answer (score 4):

> What I'm doing wrong?

You are returning a pointer to a temporary object.

```
   const char* what() const noexcept override
   {
      std::string out;
      out += prefix_;
      out += message_;
      return out.c_str();
   }
```

The pointer returned from `out.c_str()` is only valid while `out` is valid.

To fix this, you would need to call `.c_str()` on a string that has the same lifetime as the exception, such as a member variable.